# Why equation Recognizes section Above While aligned Does Not

Tags: math-mode, spacing, sectioning

I am placing equations either right after section headings, right before them or both. I know that this is not advised, but I do believe in my context it looks better. One interesting thing I noticed is that `\[...\]` (which I think just maps to `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`) recognizes when there is a `\section{...}` above it and adjusts space accordingly. However, `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` does not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength{\wthis}        % used to make rule look nice with normal text
\settowidth{\wthis}{This}

\begin{document}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\[
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\vspace{2em}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\begin{equation*}
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation*}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\vspace{2em}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\begin{align*}
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{align*}
\section*{\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}TEST}
\vspace{4em}
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.
\[
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.\par
\vspace{2em}
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.
\begin{equation*}
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation*}
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.\par
\vspace{2em}
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.
\begin{align*}
  \rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{align*}
This\rlap{\hspace{-\wthis}\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}} is a line of text for testing purposes.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In text all of these methods have the additional space as expected and therefore look good. My questions are for when these are placed in the bizarre locations of right after and right before `\section`s.

Is there a reason for this extra space being added to `align` and not `equation`? I would think that if the functionality is available in one it should work the same in the other. Also why does this not work for the extra space below (both have the additional `\belowdisplayskip` added)? Are the `\[...\]`/`\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` only able to recognize `\section`s above?

*Note:* I am not using `align*` environments for these basic equations. I simply used this basic equation to be able to use the same text in all three (actually two) environments.

Comment: Interesting, does it happen with sections only or also with regular text?

Comment: After I removed my answer and my previous comment here are some observations from the edited MWE. It can be seen that the effect does not come (at least to the same extend) when the displayed math comes after text, so an explanation as to why the vspace is larger for `align*` when it is immediately after a sectional macro might be purely academic as it is never recommended to have a displayed formula as the very first thing after a sectional header.

Comment: Yes, I am placing them most definitely in a bizarre location, almost creating a sense of undefined behavior here, but I thought the difference was rather interesting. Perhaps it has other implications.

Comment: @alfC As seen in the updated MWE it does not for regular text. I have seen this with sections. Perhaps other things as well though?

Answer (score 1):

The "original" `\[`...`\]` as well as environment `equation` uses TeX's mechanism for the vertical space. Is the line before is short, then `\abovedisplayshortskip` will be used instead of `\abovedisplayskip`.

The environments of package `amsmath` (`gather`, `align`, ...) do more complicate things with the equations (multiple lines, automatic moving of the equation number, ...). Therefore, it only uses `\abovedisplayskip`.

Example with debug code to show the main vertical list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\[ E=mc^2 \]
\section{Test}
\begin{align*} E=mc^2 \end{align*}
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1
\showlists
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]